# react-testing-library's fireEvent.click not updating result of debug() when testing react-native-web

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-native-web

So I have created a simple ConnectFour game using React https://github.com/pavilion/ConnectFourTDD

I have created a Board and Cell components. The board is composed of a table of Cells.

The test renders a 4x4 Board and clicks the first element of the first column, so the outcome would be to get a X in the bottom of the first column:

```
+--------------------+--+--+--+
| Click happens here |  |  |  |
+--------------------+--+--+--+
|                    |  |  |  |
+--------------------+--+--+--+
|                    |  |  |  |
+--------------------+--+--+--+
| X                  |  |  |  |
+--------------------+--+--+--+
```

However, when I do `debug()` which basically prints the DOM tree, it doesn't show any "X". Here is the test: [https://github.com/pavilion/ConnectFourTDD/blob/testing-library/packages/web/src/**tests**/App-test.tsx#L19](https://github.com/pavilion/ConnectFourTDD/blob/testing-library/packages/web/src/__tests__/App-test.tsx#L19)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found that the responder system doesn't rely on click events so you can't expect to dispatch those DOM events have onPress get called.

Therefore, if you are using `react-native-web` you should not write your web tests with `react-testing-library` but with `react-native-testing-library`.